# Remove numbers inside brackets if there is a leading number

Tags: php, regex

I have multiple types of strings. If it is like `number text (text)` I want to erase the content inside the brackets. Otherwise not.

This will remove everything always inside brackets.

```
/\((.*?)\)/
```

How do I check for the leading number?

Comment: do you want to remove numbers inside brackets if no leading number

Comment: No. If there is a leading number, I want to remove the text (containing numbers) inside the brackets. Otherwise the content inside the brackets must stay untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex

```
(\d[^\(\)]*?\().*?(\))
    ^           ^   ^
    |           |   |->2nd group matches )
    |           |->matches content within ()
    |->1st group would match a digit followed by 0 to many characters(except ())followed by (
```

and replace it with

```
$1$2
```

Comment: What about if the format is `number text (text)`, for example `2 km (17:00)`?

Comment: Thanks, awesome! Could you recommend any good source to learn regex?

Answer (score 2):

`\d` matches any digit. And there is a better than using ungreedy repetition:

```
/\d\s*\(([^)]*)\)/
```

If the space is mandatory, use:

```
/\d\s+\(([^)]*)\)/
```

If you do **not** want to match in the case of `a1 (text)`, use:

```
/\b\d+\s*\(([^)]*)\)/
```

For the removal, it might be easier to match the stuff around the parentheses, though (I use the first regex as an example, but this can be applied to all three cases):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\d\s*)\([^)]*\)/', '$1()', $str);
```

For the first case (if `text` in `a1 (text)` should be removed as well), and if you restrict the amount of spaces to one, you can also use a slightly more efficient variant, using a lookbehind:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\d\s)\([^)]*\)/', '()', $str);
```

The lookbehind is not included in the match, thus no need for capturing. Unfortunately, with PCRE the lookbehind has to be of fixed-lenght, which is why you cannot use it with either `\d+` or `\s*`.

Comment: variable length lookbehind `(?<=\d\s*)`

Answer (score 0):

Go with

```
$s = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $s);
```